# The Google Map API navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() giving wrong coordinates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I have used below script and code to get current position (latitude and longitude)

```js
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
  console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
  console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
}

function error(err) {
  console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places,geometry"></script>
```

Output :

```
Your current position is:
Latitude : 19.7514798
Longitude: 75.7138884
More or less 296997 meters.
```

I am developing map implementation in a react project where I need to show stores near me. I am using the above code to get my location coordinates this is working fine in a smartphone but in laptop (with GPS) browsers I am getting wrong coordinates. The distance between a current location and coordinates is about 130+ KM. Also, third party site used to find the current location also showing same location that of the coordinates.